# Why do Edge and IE not display this img-embedded-svg with text that has extended ASCII characters?

Tags: html, svg, microsoft-edge

I have an HTML page, that has a SVG in an img element. In Chrome and Firefox the img-svg is displayed. But not in Edge and IE. I have narrowed it down to the text in the SVG. The text has extended ASCII characters (i.e. ASCII codes >= 128).

---

Here the sample HTML

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>

 <body id="easykat-app">
   <!--  1. img-svg with extended ASCII -->
   <img
  src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">    <text x="0" y="15">1 Çüéâ</text>   </svg>'>

   <hr />

   <!-- 2. img-svg with HTML Numbers -->
   <img
  src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">    <text x="0" y="15">2 &#199; &#252; &#233; &#226; </text>   </svg>'>

   <hr />

   <!-- 3. img-svg with no extended ASCII -->
   <img
  src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">      <text x="0" y="15">3 @ABCD</text>    </svg>'>

   <hr />

   <!-- 4. svg with  extended ASCII -->
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" width="50" height="50"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <text x="0" y="15">4 Çüéâ</text></svg>

 </body>

 </html>
```

---

Here the expected output

[image: expected]

---

**Problem**

1. Edge and IE do not display the first and second img-svg which has text with extended ASCII characters and with HTML numbers. Firefox and Chrome display the img-svg
2. IE seems not to display any img-svg.

Here the output from Edge

[image: error in edge]

Here the 1st problematic img-svg

```html
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">    <text x="0" y="15">1 Çüéâ</text>   </svg>'>
```

---

I have tried using HTML numbers, i.e.

```html
   <!-- 2. img-svg with HTML Numbers -->
   <img
  src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">    <text x="0" y="15">2 &#199; &#252; &#233; &#226; </text>   </svg>'>
```

Again this works on Chrome and Firefox but not on Edge and IE.

---

The 4th SVG (only a svg element, no img element) is displayed in all browsers

---

Can anyone help understand this problem?

---

Browsers Versions

1. Edge 44.18362.449.0
2. IE 11.592.18362.0
3. Firefox 73.0.1 64bit
4. Chrome80.0.3987.132 64bit

Tested on Windows 10 pro 64bit

Comment: I belive IE and Edge require the data URL syntax to be correct i.e. charset=UTF-8 rather than some raw utf-8 which is technically invalid. Chrome and Firefox may simply be more forgiving here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IE seems not to display any img-svg.

IE is strict to SVG so we should optimize the data url when using SVGs in Internet Explorer.

- Most browsers are lenient about the `charset=` string, but it's required for Internet Explorer. That means you need to use `;charset=utf8,` instead of `;utf8,`.
- You will have to percent-encode characters that aren't URL-safe. For example, `<svg>` to `%3Csvg%3E`. You can minimize the amount of percent encoding that needs to be done by using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

So if you change the 3rd img-svg to the belowing, it can show well in IE:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 50 50' width='50' height='50' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1'%3E    %3Ctext x='0' y='15'%3E3 @ABCD%3C/text%3E   %3C/svg%3E">
```

But for the 1st and 2nd svg, they're still can't be displayed in IE and Edge. Seems like img-svg showing extended ASCII is not supported in IE and Edge. This might related with the browsers' rendering engines, as IE using Trident and Edge Legacy using EdgeHTML which is a fork of Trident. The new Edge based on Chromium can show all the svgs correctly.